# unable to return to main() from a method reading standard input stream

Tags: java, methods, return, command-pattern, control-flow

I am basically trying to return from a method which reads user input from the standard input stream. Since the user has the option to quit the application, I am trying to figure out the best way to do this [exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736245/what-is-an-appropriate-way-to-programmatically-exit-an-application). Ideally I will be able to return from `begin()` and let `main()` finish, thus quiting the applicaiton.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     begin();
}

private static void begin(){
        Machine aMachine = new Machine();
        String select=null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true){
            try {
                select = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("IO error trying to read your selection");
                return;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Error trying to evaluate your input");
                return;
            }

            if (Pattern.matches("[RQrq1-6]", select)) {
                aMachine.getCommand(select.toUpperCase()).execute(aMachine);
            }
            else {                
                System.out.println(aMachine.badCommand()+select);
                aMachine.getStatus();
            }
        }
    }
```

The main logic takes place when `aMachine` executes a given command by the user with this method:

```
aMachine.getCommand(select.toUpperCase()).execute(aMachine);
```

Again, the issue is how to quit the application once the user enters the command Q, or q. The quit command is like this:

```
public class CommandQuit implements Command {

    public void execute(Machine aMachine) {
        aMachine.getStatus();
        return; //I would expect this to force begin() to exit and give control back to main()
    }
}
```

Now following the advice from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736245/what-is-an-appropriate-way-to-programmatically-exit-an-application), to quit the application, I am trying to return to main() and basically let main() complete. This way I avoid any use of `System.exit(0)`, although that would be fine too.

So, in this example, I have a `return` statement in the `execute` method of the `CommandQuit` class which is called when we receive a Q, or q from the user. However, when `begin()` executes a quit command, instead of returning from the `while(true)` loop, out of `begin()`, and back into `main()`, the control flow never seems to respond to the `return;` within the `execute` method of CommandQuit.

Is there anything that I am missing in my example? Perhaps something is so obvious that I can't see it at the moment. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return statement in `execute()` returns from `execute()`, not `begin()`.  Usually in these cases, `CommandQuit.execute()` sets a flag on `aMachine`, and then `begin()` checks the flag at the top of the loop:

```
while (aMachine.stillRunning()) {  // instead of while (true)
    ...
    // This will clear aMachine.stillRunning() if the user quits.
    aMachine.getCommand(select.toUpperCase()).execute(aMachine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return;
```

always returns from the current function only (in this case CommandQuit.execute). It's exactly the same as executing past the end of the function. You could set a flag in aMachine, and make the while loop run until it's set instead of running forever:

in the class "Machine" you would have:

```
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    public boolean stillRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }
    public void stopRunning() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
```

and you would loop while aMachine.stillRunning() and call aMachine.stopRunning() to stop it.