# Rookie needing help how to quit my program in Java

Tags: java

I don't understand how I am supposed to make this program stop. Basically what it wants me to do is that when I type -1 the program shut off. I just can't figure out how. And ooh! "sida" in swedish means side. Don't know if it helps or not! Would be awesome with some help from you guys over here!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class triangle
{

//Triangle is going up
public static void triangelUpp(int sida)
{

    for(int i = 0; i <= sida; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }       
}


//Triangle going down
public static void triangelNed(int sida)
{

    for(int i = 0; i <= sida; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= sida - i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }       
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    //Variables 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int vinkel = 0;
    int sida = 0;


    //Rules
    while(sida !=-1)
    {
        if(vinkel == 0)
            triangelNed(sida);

        else if(vinkel == 1)
            triangelUpp(sida);

    System.out.println("Write the length of the triangle and end with -1");
    sida = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Is the angle going to be up(1) or down?(0)");
    vinkel = keyboard.nextInt();

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736245/what-is-an-appropriate-way-to-programmatically-exit-an-application

Comment: As written the program should end when you want it to. Does it not work the way you expect?

Comment: Easiest way: change the `while-loop` to `while(true)` and then after assign `sida`: `if (sida < 0) { break; }`

Comment: Just tried it. The program ends, but first it prints the second question. Just add an `if (side == -1) break;` before.

Comment: I see now. @LuiggiMendoza has the best answer.

Comment: I need to end the program with "  -1   " so after I type i.e 3 and then 0. I want to quit the program by typing -1. This is the only way I am allowed to do it! :p

Comment: So if user types -2 the program must continue?

Comment: That won't be a valid command. So nothing will happen at all I guess. The idea is that the program is shut down after it asks you to write -1 if you want to close it.

"Write the length of the triangle and end with -1" - Bad english from me. More like ..."and quit the program with -1"

Comment: @user2120859 answer updated. If it pleases to your needs, please mark the check below the rep.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way: change the `while-loop` to `while(true)` and then after assign sida: `if (sida < 0) { break; }`

In other words:

```
while(true) {
    //some logic here...
    sida = keyboard.nextInt();
    //if (sida < 0) {
    //since you don't like the regular approach, changing it to fit your odd needs
    if (sida == -1) {
        //breaks the while loop
        break;
    }
    //rest of code...
}
```

Using `System.exit(0)` will just kill the process, showing a sample

```
while(true) {
    //code here...
    //same here
    //if (sida < 0) {
    if (sida == -1) {
        //comment/uncomment the options to see the program behavior
        //using this, the message after the while loop will be printed
        break;
        //using this, the message after the while loop won't be printed
        //System.exit(0);
    }
}
System.out.println("Thanks! See ya later");
```

Comment: Thank you. However the thing is that it has to be shut off when you're typing -1. Therefor system.exit(0); can't be used

Comment: @user2120859 That's why I posted the difference between using `break` and `System.exit(0)`, maybe it's not clear. By the way, I use `sida < 0` because I assumed that `-2` was also a wrong input :).

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to the question, the best thing to do when programming is to write your variables and comments in English.

But break is indeed the best way to do it. Although I would check if it's equal to -1 instead of less than 0. (This is an addition to Luigi Mendoza's answer)

```
if (sida == -1) {
```

rather than

```
if (sida < 0) {
```

Comment: Again, -1 is the exit, how about -2, -3, -9001?

Comment: In the comments he says "and end with -1", so any other solution should work.. So I would be tempted to test for equals instead of less than 0. Also because I have a feeling that this is school-related and schools want it to be right to the letter..

Comment: So, if your teacher teachs you to follow bad practices you must always follow them?

Comment: Well, I know what you mean Luiggi. However, this is the way she wants it. She's been learning the same course for over 10 years. She will not adapt I guess or see new possibilities. Have to follow 100%

Comment: Is it a bad practice to specify the exit code? In my opinion it's the other way around. Who says -3 can't be a valid input? If only 0 and 1 are valid inputs, then I agree with you, but then you have to check for when it's more than 2 too. It's one or another. I agree with you that you have to secure against "the stupid user", but it depends on the specific use.

Comment: I never said specifying an exit code is a bad practice, it was an example. I guess that OP could have taken the idea of the answer instead of asking *please change `< 0` to `== -1` otherwise I can't accept it* (and this is the source of all problems... =\ )

Comment: Well, I don't think I can make it any clearer. The user can input what ever number he likes on how many aesterisk there will be. Then he chooses if it's going to be up or down. When he wants to shut the program off manually he just types in -1. Simple as that. This is the way it has to be executed I'm afraid. I'm really happy for showing me other ways and I wish I could use it. But I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score -1):

to quit the program you can use
    system.exit(0);

Comment: This is overkill he just needs to break out the loop